# Counting magnet apperance using reed switch on arduino nano

Tags: c, count, arduino, interrupt

I'm simply trying to count every time magnet appears in an area using a reed switch. I'm stuck on a little problem. When launching the program, it does not count correctly. Sometimes it follows the order but often it jumps by 2 or 3 units. Could anyone help?
Here is the code:

```
#include <SPI.h> 

int count=0;
volatile bool check = true;
volatile bool revcheck = true;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), magnet_detect, LOW);
}

void loop() {
 if(digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    check = true; }
 if(!revcheck) {
    Serial.println(count);
    revcheck = true; }
    }
  

void magnet_detect() 
{
  if(check) {
  count++;
  check = false;
  revcheck =false;
  }
}
```

Hardware set-up and output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJSr7.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBC1q.jpg

Comment: You need debouncing - there are mechanical vibrations during switching and it generates many impulses before it gets stable

Comment: check and revcheck should be initialized to false at the beginning. And as KIIV says you should debounce the input, could be done by polling the input. And it seems strange to use both polling and interrupt at the same time, so decide if you want to use polling or interrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some form of debouncing. There are standard ways to achieve this,but a simple, "poor-mans" version would look like this:

```
beginning of function()
  oldState = 0;
  do stuff
  if(the sensor reads 1 AND oldState is 0):
     counter ++
     oldState = 1

  if (the sensor reads 0 AND oldState is 1):
     oldState = 0
```

You know, the looping is faster than the physical magnet passing the switch (because a microprozessor calculates in milli, often nanoseconds). so you have to check if you actually already have scanned the magnet.

Answer (score 0):

You attach an interrupt AND check for digital state, this is wrong, it should be only one of the methods that increases the count.